# How to decode JSON object based on key prefix

Tags: json, go

I'm wondering if it is possible to decode a JSON object into struct based on prefix.

For example, I may have two JSON objects like following:

```json
{
    "id teacher": "10"
}
```

and

```json
{
    "id student": "20"
}
```

Currently I have two structs:

```golang
type Teacher struct {
    Id  string  `json:"id teacher"`
}

type Student struct {
    Id  string  `json:"id student"`
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to have one struct and decode based on the prefix of the string (for example, by regex `id.*`) assuming that there will be only one matching field.

Comment: Even if you did that, youd still have a `struct` of unknown type. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: convert json to different struct type by id?

Comment: @StevenPenny My goal is to have one struct that can be used to decode both types of json. What do you mean by "`struct` of unknown type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to create a single struct for say `Person` and have a single property `Person.Id` which can be populated by either `id teacher` or `id student`.

In native `encoding/json` syntax, you might expect to see something like the following, but Go doesn't work this way.

```golang
type Person struct {
    Id string `json:"id student|id teacher"`
}
```

One approach is to implement a custom `UnmarshalJSON` function like follows. This example uses `strings.Index` but it's just as easy to use a regular expression.

```golang
type Person struct {
    Id   string
    Role string
}

func (p *Person) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var v map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for key, val := range v {
        if strings.Index(key, "id ") == 0 {
            p.Id = val.(string)
            p.Role = key[3:]
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here's a fully operational example:

https://play.golang.org/p/1-tzUYcd5rJ